# How to write an update query that updated all double values in table with autonumbering based on count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that with the following query gives me all the double values.

```
SELECT workorder, job.count
FROM (
  SELECT workorder,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY workorder) AS count
  FROM engineering_job_schedule) AS job
WHERE job.count > 1 and workorder is not null
```

This will return something like

| workorder | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| M-22.20.171.3017 000001 | 2 |
| M-22.20.171.3017 000001 | 2 |
| M-22.20.176.3023 000001 | 2 |
| M-22.20.176.3023 000001 | 2 |

Now how would you use this query to create an `UPDATE` query to update all workorder values to a new counting-up number.

So that my new value would be

| workorder |
| --- |
| M-22.20.171.3017 000001 |
| M-22.20.171.3017 000002 |
| M-22.20.176.3023 000001 |
| M-22.20.176.3023 000002 |

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `COUNT(*)` to calculate a number for every row. The `ORDER BY` clause is required so you'll have to find a column in `engineering_job_schedule` to specify the order.

Comment: Does `engineering_job_schedule` have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `COUNT(*)` to calculate a number for every row. The `ORDER BY` clause is required so you'll have to find a column in `engineering_job_schedule` to specify the order.

Assuming the part you need to maintain is the first 16 characters, and the work order will be zero-padded to 6 digits, the query could look like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( LEFT(workorder,16),
               ' ',
               REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(RN)),
               RN)
FROM 
(
    SELECT workorder,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workorder ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RN,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY workorder) AS count
    FROM engineering_job_schedule
) job
WHERE 
    job.count>1 and workorder is not null
```

Once you're satisfied with the output you can create an `UPDATE` query based on the results of the query:

```
UPDATE job
SET 
    workorder =CONCAT( LEFT(workorder,16),
               ' ',
               REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(RN)),
               RN)
FROM 
(
    SELECT workorder,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workorder ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RN,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY workorder) AS count
    FROM engineering_job_schedule
) job
WHERE 
    job.count>1 and workorder is not null
```

Comment: Given that `RN` cannot be `>1` if `count = 1`, you could remove the windowed count altogether and just use `WHERE job.RN > 1`